# UPDATE value of String in a column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary

I have a VARCHAR column called PROPERTYDATA in table PERSON which has data like this

```
    <java.lang.String valueOf="ALLOWUSER" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="true" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="STATUSTASK" />
    <java.lang.String
        valueOf="${param.TaskOpen eq true ? true : &apos;&apos;" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="PROPERTYCOLOR" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="1" />
```

This actually shows fields created in system with their values below it e.g. value of variable name ALLOWUSER is true.

The value of STATUSTASK will always be ${param.TaskOpen eq true ? true ...

I want to write  two queries

1. Update query which will UPDATE the value of field STATUSTASK to empty i.e. "" WHERE PROPERTYCOLOR value is 1 in EACH ROW. IF the ROW data has PROPERTYCOLOR not 1 then we should leave it as it is.

so result will be

```
    <java.lang.String valueOf="ALLOWUSER" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="true" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="STATUSTASK" />
    <java.lang.String
        valueOf="" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="PROPERTYCOLOR" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="1" />
```

2. DELETE the field name and value WHERE PROPERTYCOLOR value is 1 i.e. after the query the row should now be

   ```
   <java.lang.String valueOf="ALLOWUSER" />
   <java.lang.String valueOf="true" />
   <java.lang.String valueOf="PROPERTYCOLOR" />
   <java.lang.String valueOf="1" />
   ```

Should we do like this ?

UPDATE PERSON SET PROPERTYDATA = (SUBSTRING (PROPERTYDATA))... I am stuck, please help

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you need. Please [read about MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have you tried casting to xml?

Comment: Note that `please help me write it` is often code for `please write this for me`, so I have taken it out. As above, this question is not very clear, so if you can add any additional material that would be a good idea!

Comment: this is bad xml structure, you're relying on sequential pairs of rows/values, when you should have some structure to your attributes/nodes to pair them up for you.

Comment: What to do ? The data is like this, coming from client. I can only do operations on data itself, how to do it ?

Comment: i don't see how you can easily update a value when you have no identifying information apart from the row above it, going to have to do a bunch of xml manipulation to work it all out

Comment: is that the complete structure you have for the values, for example will there be 6 nodes maximum in every row?

Comment: no they can change,,, I have thought to do it manually rather than with query as it is error prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer so to speak, but I've had a look at this and have managed to write some queries that convert to XML and query the data, which might help you get to an eventual solution, so I'll post what I've done:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      propertydata VARBINARY(MAX) ,
      propertyxml XML
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( propertydata ,
          propertyxml
        )
VALUES  ( CAST(' <java.lang.String valueOf="ALLOWUSER" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="true" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="STATUSTASK" />
    <java.lang.String
        valueOf="${param.TaskOpen eq true ? true : &apos;&apos;" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="PROPERTYCOLOR" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="1" />' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) ,
          CAST(' <java.lang.String valueOf="ALLOWUSER" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="true" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="STATUSTASK" />
    <java.lang.String
        valueOf="${param.TaskOpen eq true ? true : &apos;&apos;" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="PROPERTYCOLOR" />
    <java.lang.String valueOf="1" />' AS XML)
        )

SELECT  propertydata ,
        propertyxml
FROM    #temp

SELECT  t2.Loc.query('.') XmlRow ,
        t2.Loc.query('.').value('(/java.lang.String/@valueOf)[1]',
                                'nvarchar(100)') AS AttributeValue
FROM    #temp
        CROSS APPLY propertyxml.nodes('java.lang.String') AS t2 ( loc )
WHERE   t2.Loc.query('.').value('(/java.lang.String/@valueOf)[1]',
                                'nvarchar(100)') IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Produces:**

```
XmlRow                                                       AttributeValue
<java.lang.String valueOf="ALLOWUSER" />                     ALLOWUSER
<java.lang.String valueOf="true" />                          true
<java.lang.String valueOf="STATUSTASK" />                    STATUSTASK
<java.lang.String valueOf="${param.... />                     ${param....
<java.lang.String valueOf="PROPERTYCOLOR" />                 PROPERTYCOLOR
<java.lang.String valueOf="1" />                             1
```